# Solving a differential equation related to the hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, hypergeometric-functions

I need to solve the following equation:

$x*(1 - s*x) y''[x] + y'[x]  + r*y[x] =0,$
where $s$ and $r$  are two parameters.

It would seem that is similar to the hypergeometric differential equation, but I could not prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Have you thought about changing the variable $x$ to $z = sx$?

Comment: CAS solve this routinely -- e.g., here is [Mathematica solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5B+x*%281-s*x%29*y%27%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+y%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+r*y%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C+y%5Bx%5D%2C+x+%5D).